# utf8 conversion issue on windows using rmongodb

Tags: r, windows, mongodb, utf-8, rmongodb

I am having issues receiving proper utf8 characters using rmongodb.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmongodb_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.3        rsconnect_0.4.1.4 tools_3.2.2       rstudioapi_0.3.1  Rcpp_0.12.1       jsonlite_0.9.17
```

Using mongo shell I am getting:

```
            "organization" : [
                    {
                            "name" : "Birkhäuser Verlag GmbH",
                    }
            ],
```

In RStudio:

```
[1] "WERK BirkhÃ¤user Verlag GmbH"
```

To get the data in R, I am using:

```
mongo.find.all(mongo = mdb, ns = colname, limit = 10)
```

So the Umlaut is not handled properly.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It does work fine on OS X though.